# distance on a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

Please, can someone help me? I have the following problem:
Let $X$ be a normed space, $Y \subset X$ a linear subspace of $X$. I have to prove that the function $$d_{Y}(x)=inf\{||x-y||:y \in Y\}$$ is a seminorme;
I tried to prove that, if $a,b \in X$: $d_{Y}(a+b)\le d_{Y}(a)+d_{Y}(b)$;
I denoted by $m=d_{Y}(a+b)$, $m_{1}=d_{Y}(a)$, $m_{2}=d_{Y}(b)$; I have to prove that $m \le m_{1}+m_{2}$.
I have that there exists $y_{1} \in Y$, such that: $m_{1}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}>||a-y_{1}||$; also, there exists $y_{2}$: $m_{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}>||b-y_{2}||$, for every $\epsilon >0$;
so we will have that $m_{1}+m_{2}+\epsilon>||a-y_{1}||+||b-y_{2}||\ge ||a+b-(y_{1}+y_{2}||\ge m$; as $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily chosen, $m_{1}+m_{2}\ge m$. Is this correct?(to show that is it seminorme, I have to prove another thing, but I proved that one).

For the same problem, I have to prove that $N:X/Y \to \mathbb{R}$, $N(\overline{a})= d_{Y}(a)$ is well defined. I picked $\overline{a}, \overline{b}$ from $X/Y$, with $\overline{a}=\overline{b} $. I have to show that $N(\overline{a})=N(\overline{b})$. I have that $a−b \in Y$; $N(\overline{a})=d_{Y}(a)=inf\{||b+y′−y||:y∈Y\}$ ; $N(\overline{b})=inf\{||b−y||: y \in Y\}$ (where $a=b+y', y' \in Y$). We have that the map $f:Y \to Y$, by $f(y)=y−y′$, with $y′$ a fixed element in $Y$ is a bijection.  So as $y$ "walks" in the set $Y$ and covers it entirely, so it will do $y-y'$; so that sets are equal, so their inf-s are equal..Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $d_Y(x_1+x_2) \le \| x_1+x_2-y_1-y_2\| \le \|x_1-y_1\| + \| x_2-y_2 \|$
for all $y_1,y_2 \in Y$. Now take the $\inf$ with respect to $y_1$ and then $y_2$ to get the desired result.

$d_Y(\lambda x) \le \|\lambda x - \lambda y \| = |\lambda | \|x-y\|$ for all $y \in Y$ and so $d_Y(\lambda x) \le |\lambda |d_Y(x)$.

Similarly, $|\lambda |d_Y(x) \le |\lambda| \|x-y\|= \|\lambda x - \lambda y\|$
for all $y \in Y$, and so $|\lambda |d_Y(x) = d_Y( \lambda x)$.

Comment: But my solution is correct? what do you think about it?

Comment: Your solution is correct, but I prefer proofs that follow directly from the relevant inequality directly.

Comment: Glad to help! ${}{}$

Comment: For the same problem, I have to prove that $N:X/Y \to\mathbb{R}$, $d_{Y}(a)=N(\overline{a})$ is well defined. I picked $\overline{a}$, $\overline{ b}$ from $X/Y$, with $\overline{a}=\overline{b}$. I have to show that $N(\overline{a})=N(\overline{b})$. I have that $a-b \in Y$; $N(\overline{a})=d_{Y}(a)=inf\{||b+y'-y||: y \in Y \}$;$N(\overline{b})=inf\{||b-y||: y \in Y\}$, (where a=b+y', $y' \in Y$). We have that the map $f :Y \to Y $, by $f(y)=y-y'$, with $y'$ a fixed element in $Y$ is a bijection.

Comment: So those sets are equal: as $y$ "walks" into $Y$ and covers it entirely, so it does $y-y'$; so their inf are equal; it is correct?

Comment: If $y_k$ is a sequence in $Y$ such that $ \|a-y_k\| \to N(\bar{a})$ then $y'_k=(b-a)+y_k$ is a sequence in $Y$ such that $\|b-y'_k \| = \|a-y_k\| \to N(\bar{a})$, from which it follows that $N(\bar{b}) \le N(\bar{a})$. Switching the roles of $a,b$ gives the desired result.

Comment: But my solution is correct?Thank you for your disponibility!

Comment: @user308560: Yes, it looks correct. In general, for these sorts of things, since $d_Y$ is defined in terms of $\|\cdot\|$, I think is is easier to work from the corresponding relation for $\|\cdot\|$ and then use that to get the relation for $N$.